# How to include one zip file in ant but exclude all other zips in ant

Tags: ant

For example, I have a zip file test-data/test1.zip I want to include, and I don't want to include other zip files.

I have the following:
@includes: **/*,test-data/test1.zip
@excludes: **/*.class,.git/***/, **/*.zip

Seems the test1.zip is still not included.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to include one zip file, `test-data/test1.zip`, then just have it in the `includes` element. No need for the `**/*.zip` in the `excludes` part. The way Ant processes them is by taking the intersection (includes set, from which the excludes set is subtracted).

Comment: and if you need a different logic than "exclude wins over include" you can use selectors which give you more control using `and`, `or` and `not`.